# SQLite query > operator not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I am currently using the [android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to load a SQLite databse I have created. At the moment I can't get the following query to work:

```
SELECT ColumnX FROM TABLE WHERE L6 > 381 Limit 1;
```

This query is built using the following code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
String[] args = {arg1, arg2};
qb.setTables(TABLENAME);
Cursor c = qb.query(db, new String[] {"ColumnX"}, "? > ?", args, null, null, null, "1");
```

Here is a snippet of my data:
[image]

For example if `ColumnX = Nom` `arg1 = L8` and `arg2 = 380` then I would expect to get 25 but the cursor always returns with the first element of the Nom column.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your columns are of type integer. When you're substituting ? with arg2 it is transformed to a string.

So in the end you're calling:

```
SELECT ColumnX FROM TABLE WHERE L6 > '381' Limit 1;
```

To fix that, insert the integer manually:

```
Cursor c = qb.query(db,
        new String[] {"Nom"},
        "? > " + arg2,
        new String[] { arg1 },
        null, null, null, "1");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?` to bind literals only, not identifiers such as column names. So `L8` gets bound as string literal `'L8'` and not column name `L8`.

If you need to make the column name dynamic, you need to use regular Java string formatting methods such as `String.format()` or `StringBuilder`.